# Managing shared app 'context' across all Web API calls

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a design approach question regarding shared app 'context state' in a Web API application....

Imagine a single page application (SPA) which interacts with Web API back-end.
In that app, a user logs in, and is assigned to (or selects) a default company, branch, department, and state...Based on these 5 pieces of information, the back-end can take appropriate actions for each separate controller.

```
shared application 'context' parameters for each call
    userId
    companyId
    branchId
    departmentId
    stateId
```

Example: 
`TransactionController` has a `Reconcile` action that has its own `TransactionViewModel`. 
The client app needs to make a call passing action specific variables *in addition to shared app wide context variables*...

So, in spirit of not keeping state, I am aware of following choices (neither of which I am a fan)

**Choice 1 -** Make a base ViewModel containing shared params, and make every call a POST.

**Choice 2 -** Pass every shared id (userId, companyId, etc, etc) via URL params. Talk about ugly URLs...

I am wondering what approach have others taken?